# Adding Wix Include file throws not "hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character."

Tags: wix, include

I have a solution with 4 wix installer projects that share an include file. Everything builds fine on my dev machine. Check everything in and kick off a build. It throws the following error when running on the build machine:

```
    1>D:\agent\_work\6\s\Path\to\WixPorject\Product.wxs(3,0): error CNDL0104: Not a valid source file; detail: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.
    1>Done building project "whatever.wixProj" -- FAILED.
```

I went on the build machine and opened the solution in VS 2019 and couldn't see anything wrong. There was a NULL char at the end of my license.rtf but even after removing that I still got the same error building through VS. What I found was that if I commented out the include statement in my product.wxs, replace all the $(var.Variables) it builds fine. Both systems are using the Wix toolset v3.11.2.4516.

config.wxi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Include>
  <?define SourceDir = "D:\agent\_work\6\b" ?>
</Include>
```

product.wxs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
<?include "..\config.wxi" ?>
```

Builds with no issues on my dev machine.

Comment: Maybe test that path on the build computer: Hold down Windows key => Tap R => Paste: "D:\agent\_work\6\b" press Enter.

Comment: The directory opens fine. D: is a local drive on the build VM. In fact, for some reason, when the build fails with the error and I log onto the build machine, open the solution and just try and build one of the msi's it fails with the same error. Then - if I open the config.wxi file and say change the path to use single quotes:
<?define SourceDir = 'D:\agent\_work\6\b' ?>
build and it passes! Really frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so here was my issue. I can't believe I did not check this earlier on. So I was using a PowerShell task to do my replacement and it changed the encoding of the xml file. Didn't realize it until I did a compare of the updated file to the original in Notepad++ and it threw the "trying to compare with different encodings" warning message! So when I was opening the project in VS on the build machine, it was correcting the encoding and building.

Another note is that I didn't even have to update the path just have to use the env var, 'SourceDir = $(env.BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)' - although, still need to update the version and upgrade codes.

This is what I was using:

```
$configFile = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(Branch)\WixMSI\config.wxi"

    (Get-Content "$configFile") `
        -replace 'SourceDir = "(.*?)"', "SourceDir = ""$(Build.BinariesDirectory)""" `
        -replace 'MSIUpgradeCode = "(.*?)"', "MSIUpgradeCode = ""$(MSIUpgradeCodeHS)""" `
        -replace 'ProductVersion = "(.*?)"', "ProductVersion = ""$(Version)""" `
        -replace 'ReleaseVersion = "(.*?)"', "ReleaseVersion = ""$ReleaseVersion""" |
      Out-File "$configFile"
```

Just had to add: `Out-File "$configFile" -Encoding "utf8"`